# Can Bisection Method Find Roots of $x^{2}-4x\sin{x}+(2\sin{x})^{2}$?

Tags: numerical-methods, bisection

Let $f(x)=x^{2}-4x\sin{x}+(2\sin{x})^{2}$:
[image]
As is illustrated, $f(x)$ is obviously nonnegative for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Does bisection method work for this function? Because there are no $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a)f(b)<0$, then is biscetion method inconclusive or does it produce wrong answers? Is it possible to find the positive root using the said method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = (x - 2 \sin(x))^2$.  You can use the bisection method on $x - 2 \sin(x)$.
Or you can try finding minima of $f(x)$ by using the bisection method on $f'(x)$, and the minima turn out to be roots of $f(x)$.

The bisection method on $f(x)$ can't get started because, as you said, there are no $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

We first note that we can rewrite $f(x)$ as
$$
f(x) = (x - 2 \sin x)^2 = [g(x)]^2
$$
where
$$
g(x) = x - 2 \sin x
$$

Clearly,
$$
f(x) = 0 \iff g(x) = 0
$$

Thus, we can proceed to find the roots of $g$.

We take
$$
a = -{\pi \over 4} = -0.7854, \ \ b = {\pi \over 3} = 0.5236
$$

Note that
$$
g(a) = 0.6288 > 0, \ \ g(b) = -0.4764 < 0
$$

Thus, $g$ has a root in the interval $(a, b)$.

We define
$$
x_0 = {a + b \over 2} = -0.1309
$$

We find that
$$
g(x_0) = 0.1302 > 0
$$

Thus, $g$ has a root in the interval $(x_0, b) =  (-0.1309, 0.5236)$.

We define
$$
x_1 = {a + x_0 \over 2} = 0.1963
$$

We find that
$$
g(x_1) = -0.1938 < 0.
$$

Thus, $g$ has a root in the interval $(x_0, x_1) = (-0.1309, 0.1963)$.

Define
$$
x_2 = {x_0 + x_1 \over 2} =  0.0327
$$

Clearly,
$$
g(x_2) = -0.0327 < 0
$$

Thus, $g$ has a root in the interval $(x_0, x_2) = (-0.1309, 0.0327)$.

Define
$$
x_3 = {x_0 + x_2 \over 2} = -0.0491.
$$

Clearly,
$$
g(x_3) = 0.0490 > 0
$$

Thus, $g$ has a root in the interval $(x_3, x_2) = (-0.0491,  0.0327)$.

We define
$$
x_4 = {x_2 + x_3 \over 2} = -0.0082.
$$

Clearly,
$
g(x_4) = 0.0082 > 0
$$

Thus, $g$ has a root in the interval $(x_4, x_2) = (-0.0082, 0.0327)$.

We define
$$
x_5 = {x_4 + x_2 \over 2} = 0.0123
$$

Clearly, this process can be repeated, and it is easy to see that
the iteration sequence $\{ x_n \}$ converges to
$$
x^\star = 0,
$$
which is a zero of the function
$$
g(x) = x - 2 \sin x
$$

Hence, $ x^\star = 0$ is a zero of $f(x)$ by bisection method.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but $0$ is not the positive root. I found the positive root to two significant digits using Robert Israel's guidance to be $1.93$.

Comment: @mali1234 , This number is close to the positive root for $f(x)$, but there is a subtlety to consider.  The number 1.93 returns zero for the function to two decimal places, but this observation is distinct from the correct number for the root to two or three significant figures.  Using Newton's method (perhaps a more straightforward choice for this problem, given the information known from the graph), this root turns out to be 1.8954942609668 to 13 decimal places.  Evidenced by plugging both numbers into $f(x)$, the first three digits are 1.89.

Answer (score 0):

The method consists of building a sequence of intervals $[a_n, b_n]$ that are supposed to contain the root and such that $\lim a_n = \lim b_n$. **If you use the original $f$**, the method can only converge if, by chance, the root is either one of the $a_n$'s or one of the  $b_n$'s (this depends on the actual coding of the algorithm).